# GPIO extension board v3.0 on Raspberry Pi 3 B 1.2?

Tags: gpio, pi-3

I'm new to this stuff, so sorry for a trivial question. I bought a RPi kit with RPi 3 B 1.2 for learning purposes. It had GPIO extension board v3.0 . My RPi's GPIO has 40 pins, this extension board has 26 pins. Is it a mistake or is it possible to use this extension board with my RPi somehow? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can physically fit the board over the first 26 pins on the expansion header it should be fine.  Early Pis only had 26 pins.

See https://pinout.xyz/ for a diagram.

Pin 1 is nearest the end of the board with the SD card slot.

Comment: Unfortunately the tape's connector is too wide, I would have to cut it a bit (if it will work). So this is a mistake then, I will have to issue a complaint and request another, compatible one :/ . Thanks for help.